# Distinguish between command that typed by human and run by script

Tags: shell-script, keyboard, interactive

For example

```
$ pwd
/home/my_name
```

It is possible or not to identify that this command is typed by human or run by script.

Comment: Some commands check whether they have a controlling tty, as an approximation (it's fakeable in either direction), but when run from a shell it typically will have and when run from a script typically not.

Comment: No. There are several tests for common situations but which one to use depends on what you want to do in their false positive/negative cases. [Why do you want to do this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

No.

A script or shell function may inspect `$-` and look for an `i` (which indicates that this is an interactive shell), or it may look for a controlling tty (with `tty` for example), but neither of these are fool-proof methods.

Even if you, as `root`, logged all executed commands from a user's shell session, or looked at their shell history file, you would still not be able to tell if the commands that you see were actively typed by that user or inserted on the command line (or into the log) by a script, or through some other means.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there's really no fool-(or forge)-proof methods (at least I don't know), technically you can check the difference e.g. by:

```
root@aw [~]# set > cons
root@aw [~]# cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash

set > scri
root@aw [~]# ./test.sh
```

then

```
root@aw [~]# diff cons scri
```

There are a lot of differences, select any you like.